# Access to laravel model vars in a loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-blade

in my laravel project I've a table:

```
        Schema::create('results', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->tinyInteger('set_1')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('set_2')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('set_3')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('set_4')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('set_5')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

which is the right way to show set_* fields in a blade page?

This works but I'm sure there is a better solution

```
   @php
      $label = ['set_1', 'set_2', 'set_3', 'set_4', '5set_'];
   @endphp
   @for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
      <tr>
          <td>
{{-- I'm sure there is a better way to do that --}}
             {{ $result[$label[$i]] }}
          </td>
      </tr>
   @endfor
```

Comment: `$result['set_'. $i + 1]` ...

Comment: *"I'm sure there is a better way"* - Any time you find yourself defining `field_{X}`, reconsider. This `results` table could have a relationship to a `sets` table for example, which would allow `0-∞` Sets, instead of the hardcoded `5` sets you currently have. But, if you do go with this approach, a simple `for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)`, then `{{ $result->{"set_{$i}"} }}` would be the simple syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 // here : $i should be lower or equal 5
 @for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++)
  <tr>
      <td>
         {{ $result["set_$i"] }}
      </td>
  </tr>
 @endfor
```

i hope it was useful.